# Can I add a cordova plugin based on a Git branch?

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, branch

I do have a git repository with a MASTER branch.
I have now a new capability into a specific BRANCH of that same git project.

I wish to add the specific branch cordova plugin.

I'm aware of adding a cordova project based on GIT and GIT TAGS but I can't find anything in relation to a branch.

I'm looking for something like :

```
cordova plugin add https://mygitadresse/myproject#branch_name
```

Thank for support and suggestion;

Comment: if the github is branched properly it should work the way you specified. Check out this readme for sample - https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thank you @Gandhi. make a proper response so I can mark this question has solved.

Comment: glad it helped. Posted the answer. Please accept.Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the project's github repository is branched properly, then you should be able to install the plugin using the specific branch in the github out of the box.

```
cordova plugin add https://git.example.com/myproject#branch_name
```

Have look at [Cordova connect plugin](https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/README.md) for instance where there is a provision to install versions older than 1.6.0 using sdk_1.3 branch just like the way you wanted. Hope it helps.

Comment: So specify base on branch with '#" exactly as OP has written.

Answer (score 11):

If the plugin is not registered at `registry.cordova.io` but is located in another git repository, you can specify the git URL:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console.git
```

The git example above fetches the plugin from the end of the master branch, but an alternate git-ref such as a tag or branch can be appended after a `#` character:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console.git#r0.2.0
```

If the plugin (and its `plugin.xml` file) is in a subdirectory within the git repo, you can specify it with a `:` character. Note that the `#` character is still needed:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/someone/aplugin.git#:/my/sub/dir
```

You can also combine both the git-ref and the subdirectory:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/someone/aplugin.git#r0.0.1:/my/sub/dir
```

> Reference:
>   https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide/cli/index.html

Comment: Cordova CLI 3.3.0 is super old. `registry.cordova.io` hasn't been a thing for ages, you probably mean NPM in your first sentence.